Escape ':' in CLI command option that is expecting ':'
I am trying to run a CLI tool (Triton perf_analyzer) that takes an option --request-parameter that is formatted as <name:value:type>. The issue is that I need to pass in a string formatted JSON which of course contains : as well as double quotes. I have tried escaping the colons with several combinations of backlashes, single quotes, and double quotes but haven't gotten this to work. Is there some specific syntax that is needed in this situation?
perf_analyzer -m <model> \
    --request-parameter some_name:JSON_string:string

I've tried things like:
perf_analyzer -m <model> \
    --request-parameter some_name:{\"key\"\:\"value\"}:string

perf_analyzer -m <model> \
    --request-parameter some_name:'{\"key\"\:\"value\"}':string

perf_analyzer -m <model> \
    --request-parameter some_name:'{"key":"value"}':string

Alternatively, if anyone has experience with the tool, is there an alternate way to provide a parameter?
Edit: The error it returns is:
Error: Failed to parse --request-parameter. The value does not match <name:value:type>.

